# Java Spring: Autowire an implementation of an interface based on the value of a property in the same class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I have 2 classes

```
public class Vehicle {

     // Some irrelevant fields, not shown here.

  
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "VehicleTypeId")
     private VehicleType vehicleType;

     // 'PricingStrategy' is an interface with 2 implementations (see below)
     // This field should be autowired based on the value of this.vehicleType.GetVehicleType()
     private PricingStrategy pricingStrategy;

}



public class VehicleType {

    // Some irrelevant fields, not shown here.

    // Vehicle type has can have 4 different values.
    @Getter @Setter
    private string vehicleType;


}
```

`PricingStrategy` is an interface with 1 method and 2 implementations:

```
public interface PricingStrategy {
     double calculatePrice();
}

public class PricingStrategyA implements PricingStrategy {
    public double calculatePrice() {
      // Implementation is left out.
      return 0.5;
    }
}

public class PricingStrategyB implements PricingStrategy {
    public double calculatePrice() {
      // Implementation is left out.
      return 0.75;
    }
}
```

I want to use dependency injection to autowire either `PricingStrategyA` or `PricingStrategyB` into the `Vehicle` class based on the value of `vehicleType` in the class `VehicleType`.

In pseudocode:

```
 // Somewhere in the class 'Vehicle'.
if (vehicleType.getVehicleType() == 'X' OR 'Y' then use PricingStrategyA else use PricingStrategyB
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: You want a jpa-entity as a bean!? It is definitely "a smell", but possible.... (Better separate!) ..then you only have to reflect/decide on the "scope" of your bean... (And it's "state(ful/-lessness)") And then it is rather straight forward (documented, tutored ..) ...https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Factory, returning the correct implementation:

```
public PricingStrategy getPricingStrategy(char input) {
  return (input == 'X' || input == 'Y') 
      ? (PricingStrategyA)applicationContext.getBean("pricingStrategyA") 
      : (PricingStrategyB)applicationContext.getBean("pricingStrategyB");
}
```